# C# bitwise AND operator '&' logic

Tags: c#, logic, operators, unary-operator

I'm finding difficult to understand how the ´&´ operator works in relation to this code:

```
for(int cnt = 0; cnt < (1 << somelist.Count()); ++cnt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < somelist.Count(); ++i)
    {
        //  1 << 0 -- 1 -> 1
        //  1 << 1 -- 10 -> 2
        //  1 << 2 -- 100 -> 4
        //  1 << 3 -- 1000 -> 8
        //  1 << 4 -- 10000 -> 16
        //  1 << 5 -- 100000 -> 32

        var l = (1 << i);
        if ((cnt & l) == 0)
        {
            // when is it getting here?
            // some code to execute
        }

    }
}
```

which ones are the cases when it enters the if condition and those where it doesn't? and why?

I already used the debugger on it, it is the logic behind that it's not clear. What it does is:

```
e.g.

var cnt = 0
var l = 1
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // true }

var cnt = 1
var l = 1
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // false }

var cnt = 1
var l = 2
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // true }

var cnt = 1
var l = 4
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // true }

var cnt = 3
var l = 2
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // false }

var cnt = 3
var l = 4
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // true }
```

Comment: Why don´t your simply try it out using the debugger?

Comment: What's the point of the lists if you're just using the counts?

Comment: It's called the Bitwise AND operator and works like `72 & 184 = 8` = `01001000 & 
10111000 = 
00001000`

Comment: @MatthewWatson  check last edit

Comment: @HimBromBeer check last edit. I did use the debugger. It's the logic behind the & operator what I'm asking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand how & bit wise and operator work.

[Bitwise AND Operator: &](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0zec0b2.aspx)

> The bitwise AND operator (&) compares each bit of the first operand to
>   the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1, the
>   corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding
>   result bit is set to 0.

To keep the things simple I took only one byte to explain.

**First case**

```
var cnt = 1
var l = 1
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // false }

00000001
00000001
===============
00000001
```

Comparing 00000001 which is 1 with zero will return false as 1 is not equal to zero.

**Second Case**

```
var cnt = 1
var l = 2
if ((cnt & l)==0){ // true }

00000001
00000010
===============
00000000
```

Comparing 00000000 which is 0 with zero will return true as 0 is equal to zero.

Comment: [Here's a tut for OP](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) it's for c and c++ but bits are bits.